# Java equivalent for C++'s “std::string::find_first_not_of”

Tags: java, string

Is there any Java equivalent for C++'s "std::string::find_first_not of"?

I have:

```
std::string path = "some path";
std::string eol = "some text";

size_t nextLinePos = path.find_first_not_of("\r\n", eol);
```

How i can do this on Java?

Ps: For `std::find_first_of` i use this function:

```
    public static int findFirstOf(String findIn, String letters, int position)
    {
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[" + letters + "]");
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(findIn);
         if (matcher.find()) 
         {
             position = matcher.start();
         }

         return position;
    }
```

Maybe here need change something?

Comment: You may want to explain what `find_first_not_of` does, to begin with.

Comment: I suspect including `^` after the opening of the character class in the regex would do what you want, but I don't really know what `find_first_not_of` does and I'm only guessing based on the name.

Comment: To start off, your `findFirstOf` is buggy. Try `findFirstOf("x", "^y", 0);`. You need to escape the `letters`. Furthermore, your `position` parameter is currently a bit useless and misleading.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca If i think in right way then ```std::find_first_not_of``` finds the first character that is not equal to any of the characters in the passed character sequence.

Comment: Maybe Java has some lib like Apache Commons, or Google Guava to help with it?

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent method in `java.lang.String`. How would you implement the same login in Java, though, depends more on which exact implementation you wish to have. Even in C++, as far as I looked up, method is overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can write that in a very straightforward way:

```java
static int findFirstNotOf(String in, String notOf, int from) {
    for (int i = from; i < in.length(); ++i) {
        if (notOf.indexOf(in.charAt(i)) == -1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm referring to the function described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - here's my implementation.

```
    static int findFirstNotOf(final String searchIn, final char[] chars, final int pos) {
    if (pos >= 0) {
        for (int i = pos; i < searchIn.length(); i++) {
            final char current = searchIn.charAt(i);
            boolean found = false;
            for (final char c : chars) {
                found |= current == c;
            }
            if (!found) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static int findFirstNotOf(String searchIn, String searchFor, int searchFrom) {
   // char[] chars = searchFor.toCharArray();
    boolean found;
    char c;
    for (int i = searchFrom; i < searchIn.length(); i++) {
        found = true;
       // for (char c : chars) {
        c = searchIn.charAt(i);
            System.out.printf("s='%s', idx=%d\n",c,searchFor.indexOf(c));
            if (searchFor.indexOf(c) == -1) {
                found = false;
            }
      //  }
        if (!found) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String str =  "look for non-alphabetic characters...";

     int  found = findFirstNotOf(str,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ",0);

      if (found!=str.length()) {
        System.out.print("The first non-alphabetic character is " + str.charAt(found));
        System.out.print(" at position " + found + '\n');
      }
}
```

Comment: You have given your approach through code. If there is an explanation of the code and explanation about other ways to solve the problem, the solution would be more helpful.